What makes polymers have low static/sliding friction?
right now I am looking into polymers in application where they are used for their low friction and high wear resistance such as PTFE, POM or PA6.
I am interested to understand why these polymers have these properties and when developing new polymers for this application which parameters are of interest.
Many explanations point towards intermolecular forces in the adhesion such as Van der Waals, or hydrogen bridges but this is not really satisfying. First of all I am not aware of a table that gives me the adhesion force for different polymers towards e.g. steel, on the other hand there is also no clear polarity in the polymers.
Hard materials usually glide well like steel on steel so would PLA as a very hard polymer be an option of interest? Or is it maybe correlated to the density of the polymer? I could imagine that wear resistance is linked to chain length as I can remove smaller chains from the material more easily?
Maybe in the end its just about try and error so I would have to test new polymers but that would be the least satisfying option as it has nothing to do with science :-)

Your question shows understanding, but the answer is not simple -- there is a whole branch of science devoted to tribology. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribology. You can get samples to see if they meet your needs, e.g., https://www.interstateplastics.com/Friction-Resistance-Material-Sample-Pack-Accessories-eafrictionresistance.php

I know about tribology but intil know I have not found an explanation of structure-property relationship. Thats why also a sample set is not realy helping when you want to develop new polymers. I need to get an understanding of the linkage between polymer structure and the trobology properties, thats what I am looking for.
